# Kinesis Batch size and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have confusion about Kinesis Batch size and Lambda
suppose our batchsSize is 100 and Kinesis got 200 notifications. Then It will trigger 2 lambda threads?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like this by default. By [default](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-parallelization-factor-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/):

> Lambda invokes a function with **one batch of data records from one shard at a time**.

To process multiple batches from same shard at the same time you have to setup:

> **Concurrent batches per shard** – Process multiple batches from the same shard concurrently.